# How to get distinct values from 2 different columns in the same list

Tags: list, linq, lambda

So as you can see from the code bellow i have a list object named Matches, from which i would like to get a single list of the distinct teams, both from HomeTeam and AwayTeam. I'm trying to use LINQ and i can get a list of distinct teams if i only use HomeTeam parameter or AwayTeam parameter but not both together.

Thank you.

```
public class Match
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Championship { get; set; }
    public string Seasson { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public int HomeScore { get; set; }
    public int AwayScore { get; set; }
    public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
}

private List<Match> Matches;

Matches = dataAccess.GetAllMatches();
```

I'm Trying to do something like that:

result = Matches.Select(HomeTeam, AwayTeam).Distinct().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

At the risk that this smells like homework, a hint rather than code. Get your Home teams, Union your Away teams and apply a Distinct to the result.

Answer (score 0):

So i finally come up with this solution.

Notice that now i need also to get not only the team but the country which the team belongs to.

```
public class Team
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

So Union really do the job here but since now i need to get it as an anonymous type... here is the code:

```
List<Team>  teams =  new List<Team>();

var result = Matches.Select(x => new { Name = x.HomeTeam, Country = x.Country }).Union(Matches.Select(x => new { Name = x.AwayTeam, Country = x.Country })).ToList();

foreach (var record in result)
{
teams.Add(new Team { Name = record.Name, Country = record.Country });
}

 return teams;
```

I would prefer this way:

```
List<Team> teamsResult = Matches.Select(x => new Team { Name = x.HomeTeam, Country = x.Country }).Union(Matches.Select(x => new Team { Name = x.AwayTeam, Country = x.Country })).ToList();
```

But this way get duplicates so i will stick with the first example for now.

Do you think it is the more elegant way to go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx), like this:

```
IEnumerable<Team> teams = Matches.GroupBy(m => new { m.AwayTeam, m.HomeTeam, m.Country })
                .Select(
                    g =>
                        new[]
                        {
                            new Team {Country = g.Key.Country, Name = g.Key.AwayTeam},
                            new Team {Country = g.Key.Country, Name = g.Key.HomeTeam}
                        })
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .GroupBy(t => new { t.Name, t.Country })
                .Select(g => new Team { Name = g.Key.Name, Country = g.Key.Country });
```